# Prove that for arbitrary n, m, there is a n in m network which all points are not visible there

Tags: graph-theory

A **visible point** is a point which from $(0, 0)$, a line can be plotted without other points in between (from $(0, 0)$ a visible point can be seen directly).

**Prove that for arbitrary $n$, $m$, there is a n in m network in which all points are not visible there.**

points are $(x, y)$ which $ x, y  \in \mathbb{Z}$.

What came to my mind is that by transferring each point in a way in which the ratio of $x$ and $y$ remains unchangeable, we can have new networks. But it doesn't prove the problem.

Comment: 1. What is an "n in m network"? 2. When you say all points are not visible, do you mean no points are visible, or not all points are visible?

Comment: @TonyK 1. Imagine we have a rectangular with size $n * m$ and we just consider points which $x, y \in Z$  ...2. I mean no points are visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point $(x,y)$ is visible if and only if $\gcd(x,y)=1$. So just take points of the form $(N!+j+2,N!+k+2)$ for large enough $N$. This works because $\gcd(N!+j,N!+k)\ge\min(j,k)$ if $j,k\le N$.

Comment: Thanks, gcd(N!+j,N!+k)≥min(j,k) : what is the proof of this equation?

Comment: If $j,k\le N$, then $j$ divides $N!+j$, and $k$ divides $N!+k$.